# Is the Sefer standing upright or downright upside down

Tags: halacha, kavod

A sefer has a cover that when the cover of the sefer is standing upright the contents of the sefer are upside down. Which way would be the correct way to keep the sefer. It may be כבוד הספר to store it with the cover standing upright for 
then it looks respectful.

See שלחן ערוך אורח חיים סימן כ"ח סעיף ב'‏ where you see that some keep their תפילין של יד on top of the של ראש and still we keep the תפילין bag upright although through that the של יד lays on the של ראש all day perhaps because the bag 
is in its right position.

Comment: +1for the question. When I had a book with the cover on upside down, I stuck stickers on the front and the spine showing the correct orientation of the contents and kept it that way.

Comment: I've had this question myself. To me, it comes down to making the determination whether the כבוד הספר is about how other people view the Sefer respectfully, or about respecting the sefer itself and its content.

Answer (score 1):

The Sefer Chadsidim in entry #943 writes:

> לא ישא ספר להפך כדי שלא יהפוך מה למעלה למטה
>
> Don't carry a Sefer upside down so that you won't put what is meant to be on top on the bottom.

This suggests that the issue is the inside.